# How to add two configurations for api and web app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

How can I add two configurations for my spring boot where one config is for api and another config for web app

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can add two configs in main class of config  each inner class extended with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. order

```
Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig   
{


@Configuration
    @Order(1)
    @EnableWebSecurity
    class ApiConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
  {
    ......
   }


   @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    @EnableWebSecurity
    class WebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
  {

    ......
   }


 }
```